# Linq query with contains method of list of int in where condition

Tags: c#, string, linq, list, split

I don't understand what is wrong in this syntax.

```
tags="abc,xyz,asdf"
List<string> ta= tags.Split(',').ToList<string>();
List<string> demo = from T in db.tokens where ta.Contains(T.tname) select T.Id;
```

I have table with tags and their ids in it.I need to gets ids of the tags from the table...
Thank You

EDIT::
I have changed it to something like this.And its working and another problem

```
List<int> demo = from T in db.tokens where ta.Contains(T.tname) select T.Id).ToList();
var slist = from I in db.institutes
                    from T in db.inst_to_token
                    where I.CountryId == cont
                       && demo.Contains(T.tokenid)
            select I;
```

But the above is showing this error at the where condition

> The best overloaded method match for System.collection.generic.List.Contains(int) has some invalid arguments

Comment: What's the type of `T.Id`? Is it a string?

Comment: If you have another question, **ask another question**

Comment: Yes Selman22, you are right...

Comment: The best overloaded method match for System.collection.generic.List<int>.Contains(int) has some invalid arguments....BTW the data type of tokenid is int

Comment: Are you sure `T.tokenid` is an integer? NOT `int?` ?

Comment: Ya its int?....what is diff between the two

Comment: But how to change it to int as it directly comes from datatbase....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `T.tokenid` is an `int?`, you need to select `inst_to_token` where `tokenid` is not null and pass `T.tokenid.Value` to `demo.Contains` method

```
var slist = from I in db.institutes
                from T in db.inst_to_token
                where I.CountryId == cont
                   && T.tokenid.HasValue
                   && demo.Contains(T.tokenid.Value)
        select I;
```